# Replace every value in a pandas dataframe series

Tags: regex, pandas, replace

So I have a Dataframe where I want to replace every value with a new string.

(Usually I would just do df["col1"] = "string", however I need to use loc before, which creates a copy and does not manipulate the series in place)

So currently I have a df like this
`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aaaa', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})`

And when I replace it with the replace function

`df.A.replace(".*","test", regex= True, inplace= True)`

I get something like this

[image]

However what I want is something like this:

[image]

Why does it give me "test" twice. And how can I fix it?

Edit:
So to show you what the actual problem was. I will give you this example, to show you the whole picture.
Basically I have this two things

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
replace_list = ["aa","bb"]
```

Now I want the df to replace every entry where an item in the list is present with the item in the list. So the df would look like this:

[image]

Comment: You are matching between zero and unlimited times, resulting in two positions. One for the character a etc and one for right after that. This is because you havent specificed a starting position. If you include a start string ancor it will work well

Comment: yeah that's probably it. But what do you mean by start string ancor?

Comment: With that I meant try `^.*`

Comment: well as you can see it does not work. 
In my original df I have a list of places. But many of them have incorrect names.
I want to replace them with common names, if their name is part of a common one.

Comment: @JvdV if you make a new answer out of that I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern matches multiple positions. One before a character (including a character) and one right after. You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/V4sNgQ/1).

If you include a start string ancor it will work to match anything (even empty strings) and replace with `Test`

```
^.*
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aaaaa', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
# in case you want to substitute only a generic subset
df.loc[df['A'] == 'b', :] = 'test'
# in case you want the whole column
df['A'] = 'test'
```

Probably regex is an overkill =).

Comment: if the df contains of something like this
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['aaaaaa', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
I will get "test" more often when I use  "." for regex

Comment: so you want to return 'test' for every match or you have a special pattern matching? Then give more example about your pattern and adjust your question accordingly

Comment: I want "test" as an output for every row, no matter what was there before, correct.
I will adjust the post to make it clear

Comment: edited, see if it helps

Comment: mhh not sure. The problem is, that I want this only to apply in certain rows, which is why I build a mask in my real code. Let me edit the post again, so that you see what I mean. I didn't want to make it that complicated initially.

Comment: mmm I still do not get why anyone would want to use a `regex` for any string when you can just replace the column in simpler ways.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't explain it to you better. I now wrote a function that does the job and works a lot faster